# Completing inorganic reactions and writing spectator ions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions

> Complete the following reactions and write the spectators for each if any
>
> A. cobalt(II) chloride (aq) and cesium phosphate (aq)

I am not quite sure if I have the correct answer to this equation, but I have $\ce{ CoCl2(aq) + Cs(PO4)(aq)}$ (for the equation setup) and for spectator ions $\ce{Co^2+ (aq) + 2 Cl- (aq) + Cs^+ (aq) + (PO4) (aq) -> CsCl(aq) + Co(PO4)2(s)}$ and so for the spectators I have $\ce{Cs^+(aq)\ and\ 2Cl- (aq)}$, Is this correct?

> B. sodium phosphate (aq) and calcium chloride (aq)

For this equation I have $\ce{6Na^+\ and\ 6Cl-}$ as spectator ions, $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2(s)}$ (as a solid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For B, you have correctly identified [calcium phosphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricalcium_phosphate) as the precipitate, as it is the least soluble of all possible compounds. In the case of A, [cobalt phosphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_phosphate) precipitates from the solution containing cobalt(II) and phosphate salts.

$$\ce{3Ca^{2+} + 2PO4^{3-} ->~ Ca3(PO4)2\downarrow}$$
$$\ce{3Co^{2+} + 2PO4^{3-} ->~ Co3(PO4)2\downarrow}$$